# Broken link element in Outlook and Windows

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have created an email template with a link that acts as a button. But what style i do, all of it is being removed. I have put the link in table wrapper and the issue was solved but the issue was link was clickable only where there is text unlike normal link styling.

When i use the code in the following style

```
<div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#" title="Title text" class="button-link" style="text-decoration: none;border-radius: 2px;background-color: #4169e1;text-align: center;padding: 10px 0px;border: 1px solid #4169e1;text-decoration: none;color: #fff;font-size: 13px;">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

I get a broken link in outlook and email as in the screenshot [image]

But when i use a table wrapper and place the link inside table cell, issue was solved but the issue was link was clickable only where there is text unlike normal link styling.

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="my-block" id="button" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="button-wrapper">
            <a href="#" title="Title text" class="button-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Click Here</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;height:40px;text-decoration: none;border-radius: 2px;text-align: center;padding: 10px 0px;border: 1px solid #4169e1;text-decoration: none;color: #fff;font-size: 13px;" fillcolor="#4169e1" stroke="false">
 <w:anchorlock/>
 <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <center style="v-text-anchor:middle;text-decoration: none;text-decoration: none;color:#ffffff;font-size: 13px;">Click Here</center>
 </v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#" title="Title text" class="button-link" style="text-decoration: none;border-radius: 2px;background-color: #4169e1;text-align: center;padding: 10px 0px;border: 1px solid #4169e1;text-decoration: none;color: #fff;font-size: 13px;">Click Here</a>
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Added VML script for outlook support

Comment: This gives extra width to buttons in windows mail and outlook. no padding on gmail

Comment: you can play with width and height, I just gave you how to work with.

Comment: width and height not taking in outlook

Comment: You can do it without VML (unless you want rounded corners). Check out my code above :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give this piece of code a go. It will work across all email clients the same. If you change border radius, it will only work on supported email clients.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #3498db; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="#3498db" align="center"> <a href="" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #3498db; border: solid 1px #3498db; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #3498db;">Take action now</a> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Currently i am unable to test the code. Once i check the code, i will update you. Thanks for your time.